# How to apply function to pandas DataFrame, but with existing DataFrame attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, apply

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

X = pd.DataFrame(randn(100,3))
print(X.var())
```

The above code prints the variance (an attribute) of each column of a pandas DataFrame `X` (a matrix), returning a 3-element panda Series. How can apply a function to this DataFrame that multiplies the attribute `var`?

The input to the `apply` function should be the desired function. However,

```
X.apply(2 * X.var())
```

doesn't work, which tells me I can't use the DataFrame variance function itself as an input, but I would like to use it. I realize I haven't passed an iterable

Comment: Can't you just use `X.var() * 2`? What is the point of using `df.apply` here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ddof` argument:

```
print(X.var(ddof=2))
```

You don't need `apply`.

Comment: it gives the same answer whether pre- or post-multiplied

Comment: @develarist Edited mine